# How to interpret the size of weighted mean difference (WMD) in a meta analysis?

Tags: meta-analysis, weighted-mean

I am studying Kishi T, Matsunaga S, Iwata N (2015) and they report that the weighted mean difference for the outcome "Total Time in Bed" is -20.16. Is there a rule of thumb to assess whether the effect is small, moderate or large? How do I interpret the value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A (weighted) mean difference is the difference between effect estimates for intervention and control on a specific scale. Assuming this is the study you are referring to [this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4552781/#pone.0136910.s005), your scale is time measured in minutes. So, a mean difference of -20.16 would mean that that the subjective total sleep time (sTST) was 20.16 minutes less in the placebo arm. Normally I would expect this not to be a negative number as we usually set up these analyses as Intervention/ Comparator but in this case it seems they analyzed it as Placebo/ Suvorexant and that's why they have reported statistically significant results that are negative in favor of Suvorexant.

From a clinical perspective, interpretation requires knowing the minimally important difference (MID) for this outcome. This is a clinical judgement, often attained through expert opinion or consensus. It also takes into account the confidence intervals (−25.01 to −15.30). In this case, the lower confidence interval is ~15 minutes. Would this be clinically-relevant? A statistical test won't answer that question, but it's rather clinical judgement.

Comment: Excellent answer! Natale and others (2015) report that the average sTST for people with insomnia is 368 minutes while for healthy sleepers is 436. So an improvement of 20 minutes is only 25% of what is needed to bring somebody from one group to another, it feels a small improvement and not worth the side effects and the costs.